# Is it possible to code a condition in Tensorflow which is not a tensor?

Tags: python, if-statement, tensorflow, conditional-statements

I would like to have this fonction and I don't know if it is possible :

```
x=tf.constant([1,2,3])
```

the equivalent of `tf.greater(x[1],x[2])` with a type `bool` (not tensor of bool) to be used in a if then else condition

the code `tf.cond(tf.greater(x[1],x[2]),lambda : (),lambda: ())` is a condition to make an other node so it doesn't work :(

Comment: You do not need tf functions on non-tensors object

Comment: yes but I need to do the opposite : use a function (non tf) on tensor object